# XAML com parâmetro - BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, thread, xaml

Estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação XAML que solicita 2 datas. As datas são passadas como parâmetro para alguns métodos invocados pelo Evento click do botão. O problema é que durante a execução dos métodos o formulário permanece travado.

Como utilizar o BackgroundWorker ou outro recurso de Threads para resolver esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dataInicial = new DateTime();
    DateTime dataFinal = new DateTime();
    dataInicial = (DateTime)dtInicial.SelectedDate;
    dataFinal = (DateTime)dtFinal.SelectedDate;

    progressbar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    progressbar1.IsIndeterminate = true;

    thread = new Thread(() => {         

        relatorio1 r1 = new relatorio1();
        r1.gerarDados(dataInicial, dataFinal);
        relatorio2 r2 = new relatorio2();
        r2.gerarDados(dataInicial, dataFinal);
        relatorio3 r3 = new relatorio3();
        r3.gerarDados(dataInicial, dataFinal);
        relatorio4 r4 = new relatorio4();
        r4.gerarDados(dataInicial, dataFinal);
        MessageBox.Show("Sucesso !!!");          

    });

    thread.Start();
    progressbar1.IsIndeterminate = false;




}
```

No código atual eu resolvi o problema de travamento instanciando uma Thread diretamente através de Lambda. O problema é que eu não consigo alterar as propriedades da ProgressBar do Formulário assim que a Thread Termina. Gostaria de definir para false o evento IsIndeterminate mas não obtive sucesso. Acredito que com Backgroundworker seja possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução pra esse problema é bem mais simples do que isso. Inclusive, uma das maiores vantagens do C# é o quão fácil você consegue trabalhar com métodos assíncronos sem precisar gerenciar threads manualmente.

Tudo o que você precisa é iniciar o método onde todo o processamento ocorre numa `Task` e esperar que ela termine usando `await`. Olha só como ficou a nova versão do teu código:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var beginDate = begin.SelectedDate;
    var endDate = end.SelectedDate;

    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        relatorio1 r1 = new relatorio1();
        r1.gerarDados(beginDate , endDate);
        relatorio2 r2 = new relatorio2();
        r2.gerarDados(beginDate , endDate);
        relatorio3 r3 = new relatorio3();
        r3.gerarDados(beginDate , endDate);
        relatorio4 r4 = new relatorio4();
        r4.gerarDados(beginDate , endDate);

    });

    MessageBox.Show("Sucesso!");
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Apenas um adendo: na atual versão do código, é possível clicar no botão várias vezes enquanto o processamento ocorre, o que faria com que os relatórios sejam gerados várias vezes. Pra resolver isso você pode usar tanto um `lock` quanto simplesmente desabilitar o botão enquanto o processamento não for concluído.

Comment: Obrigado Roney, funfou ! Valeu pela dica do botão, optei por desabilitá-lo durante o processamento.